# How can I import python packages using knit r?

Tags: r, knitr

I am looking to integrate python code into a r notebook (or even a rmarkdown document). I am able to run Python using a python code chunk:

````
```{python} 

```
````

However I am unable to import a package (e.g. pandas). I have anaconda installed which has pandas installed, however I am unable to import it. Can anyone give me direction as to how I can import packages into r via knitr, preferably using anaconda?

Comment: Embedding pandas or numpy with Knittr works on my machine,  so that is certainly doable. I use anaconda too, but i think the default python is gcc (which also has pnadas etc) .`import sys; print sys.version  `  in my Rmd file  shows me  GCC instead of conda.  So the issue probably is how to force it not to use the default python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{python, engine.path="/path/to/your/anaconda3/bin/python"}
```

Comment: Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.